# Resuming rsync partial (-P/--partial) on an interrupted transfer

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, partial, remote-backup

I am trying to backup my file server to a remove file server using rsync. Rsync is not successfully resuming when a transfer is interrupted. I used the partial option but rsync doesn't find the file it already started because it renames it to a temporary file and when resumed it creates a new file and starts from beginning.

Here is my command:

`rsync -avztP -e "ssh -p 2222" /volume1/ myaccont@backup-server-1:/home/myaccount/backup/ --exclude "@spool" --exclude "@tmp"`

When this command is ran, a backup file named **OldDisk.dmg** from my local machine get created on the remote machine as something like **.OldDisk.dmg.SjDndj23**.

Now when the internet connection gets interrupted and I have to resume the transfer, I have to find where rsync left off by finding the temp file like **.OldDisk.dmg.SjDndj23** and rename it to **OldDisk.dmg** so that it sees there already exists a file that it can resume.

How do I fix this so I don't have to manually intervene each time?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Use `--timeout=X` (X in seconds) to change the default rsync server timeout, not `--inplace`.

The issue is the rsync server processes (of which there are two, see `rsync --server ...` in `ps` output on the receiver) continue running, to wait for the rsync client to send data.

If the rsync server processes do not receive data for a sufficient time, they will indeed timeout, self-terminate and cleanup by moving the temporary file to it's "proper" name (e.g., no temporary suffix). You'll then be able to resume.

If you don't want to wait for the long default timeout to cause the rsync server to self-terminate, then when your internet connection returns, log into the server and clean up the rsync server processes manually.  However, you [must politely terminate](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2006-April/015304.html) rsync -- otherwise, it will not move the partial file into place; but rather, delete it (and thus there is no file to resume).  To politely ask rsync to terminate, do not `SIGKILL` (e.g., `-9`), but `SIGTERM` (e.g., `pkill -TERM -x rsync` - only an example, you should take care to match only the rsync processes concerned with your client).

Fortunately there is an easier way: use the `--timeout=X` (X in seconds) option; it is passed to the rsync server processes as well.

For example, if you specify `rsync ... --timeout=15 ...`, both the client and server rsync processes will cleanly exit if they do not send/receive data in 15 seconds.  On the server, this means moving the temporary file into position, ready for resuming.

I'm not sure of the default timeout value of the various rsync processes will try to send/receive data before they die (it might vary with operating system).  In my testing, the server rsync processes remain running longer than the local client.  On a "dead" network connection, the client terminates with a broken pipe (e.g., no network socket) after about 30 seconds; you could experiment or review the source code.  Meaning, you could try to "ride out" the bad internet connection for 15-20 seconds.

If you do not clean up the server rsync processes (or wait for them to die), but instead immediately launch another rsync client process, two additional server processes will launch (for the other end of your new client process).  Specifically, the new rsync client **will not** re-use/reconnect to the existing rsync server processes.  Thus, you'll have two temporary files (and four rsync server processes) -- though, only the newer, second temporary file has new data being written (received from your new rsync client process).

Interestingly, if you then clean up all rsync server processes (for example, stop your client which will stop the new rsync servers, then `SIGTERM` the older rsync servers, it appears to merge (assemble) all the partial files into the new proper named file.  So, imagine a long running partial copy which dies (and you think you've "lost" all the copied data), and a short running re-launched rsync (oops!).. you can stop the second client, `SIGTERM` the first servers, it will merge the data, and you can resume.

Finally, a few short remarks:

- Don't use `--inplace` to workaround this.  You will undoubtedly have other problems as a result, `man rsync` for the details.
- It's trivial, but `-t` in your rsync options is redundant, it is implied by `-a`.
- An already compressed disk image sent over rsync *without* compression might result in shorter transfer time (by avoiding double compression).  However, I'm unsure of the compression techniques in both cases.  I'd test it.
- As far as I understand `--checksum` / `-c`, it won't help you in this case.  It affects how rsync decides if it *should* transfer a file.  Though, after a first rsync completes, you could run a *second* rsync with `-c` to insist on checksums, to prevent the strange case that file size and modtime are the same on both sides, but bad data was written.

Comment: Just curious: wouldn't `SIGINT` (aka `^C`) be 'politer' than `SIGTERM`?

Comment: I didn't test how the server-side rsync handles SIGINT, so I'm not sure it will keep the partial file - you could check.  Note that this doesn't have much to do with `Ctrl-c`; it happens that your terminal sends `SIGINT` to the foreground process when you press `Ctrl-c`, but the server-side rsync has no controlling terminal. You must log in to the server and use `kill`. The client-side rsync will not send a message to the server (for example, after the client receives `SIGINT` via your terminal `Ctrl-c`) - might be interesting though. As for anthropomorphizing, not sure what's "politer". :-)

Comment: I just tried this timeout argument `rsync -av --delete --progress --stats --human-readable --checksum --timeout=60 --partial-dir /tmp/rsync/ rsync://$remote:/ /src/` but then it timed out during the "receiving file list" phase (which in this case takes around 30 minutes). Setting the timeout to half an hour so kind of defers the purpose. Any workaround for this?

Comment: @user23122 `--checksum` reads all data when preparing the file list, which is great for many small files that change often, but should be done on-demand for large files.

Answer (score 14):

Sorry but the other answers here are too complicated :-7.
A simpler answer working for me: (using rsync over -e ssh)

```
# optionally move rsync temp file, then resume using rsync 
dst$ mv .<filename>.6FuChr <filename>
src$ rsync -avhzP --bwlimit=1000 -e ssh <fromfiles> <user@somewhere>:<destdir>/
```

Works also when resuming from an scp which was interrupted.

Rsync creates a temporary file ... The temporary file grows quickly to size of partially transferred file. Transfer resumes.

Scp writes to the actual end destination file . If transfer is interrupted this is a truncated file.

Explaination of args:

-avhz .. h=humanoid, v=verbose, a=archive, z=compression
.. archive instructs it to maintain time_t values so even if clocks are out rsync knows the true date of each file

-P is short for --partial --progress. 
 --partial tells rsync to keep partially transferred files (and upon resume rsync will use partially transferred files always after checksumming safely)

From man pages:
http://ss64.com/bash/rsync_options.html

```
--partial
By default, rsync will delete any partially transferred file if the transfer
is interrupted. In some circumstances it is more desirable to keep partially
transferred files. Using the --partial option tells rsync to keep the partial
file which should make a subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster.

--progress
This option tells rsync to print information showing the progress of the transfer.
This gives a bored user something to watch.
This option is normally combined with -v. Using this option without the -v option
will produce weird results on your display.

-P
The -P option is equivalent to --partial --progress.
I found myself typing that combination quite often so I created an option to make
it easier.
```

**NOTE: for a connection which is interrupted multiple times:**
If you need to resume after rsync (after the connection is interrupted) then it is best to rename the temporary file on destination. scp creates a file on destination with same name as final file. If scp is interrupted this file is a truncated version of the file. An rsync (-avzhP) will resume from that file but start writing to a temporary file name like ..Yhg7al.

Procedure when starting with scp:

```
scp; *interrupt*; rsync; [REPEAT_as_needed: *interrupt*; mv .destfile.tmpzhX destfile; rsync;].
```

Procedure when starting with rsync:

```
rsync; [REPEAT_as_needed: *interrupt*; mv .destfile.tmpzhX destfile; rsync;].
```

Comment: But [this site](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+--timeout%3D60+--archive+--partial+--append-verify+--progress+--stats+user%40host%3A%2Ffolder+%2Fcygdrive%2Ff%2Fbackup) says `--progress` implies `--verbose`.

Comment: `--partial` keeps partial files, but to resume from those, one should use `--append` or `--append-verify` and the target should be smaller than the source, [despite the source having a more recent time stamp.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/can-rsync-resume-after-being-interrupted/165417?noredirect=1#comment405796_165417)

Comment: If you need to resume again (the rsync connection is interrupted) then best to rename temportary file on destination. So procedure when starting with scp: scp *interrupt* rsync [REPEAT_as_needed: *interrupt* mv_desttmp_destfile rsync]. Procedure when starting with rsync: rsync [REPEAT_as_needed: *interrupt* mv_desttmp_destfile rsync].

Answer (score 2):

I found that adding --inplace fixes it. Not sure how --partial is supposed to work without it but it resumed my transfers. My files are still pretty big though and I'm wondering if I will end up with corrupt files if a transfer starts and hours later another transfer starts but sees an incomplete file and doesn't know its currently being uploaded which then starts adding bytes to it. Anyone know? Maybe some bash scripting to log the current process id and not start another transfer?

Comment: Be careful with inplace as it can also do more harm than good. It is known to cause further inconsistencies if a file is currently being accessed by others.

Comment: [`--append-verify` implies `--inplace`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html) but skips content that doesn't need appending.

Answer (score 0):

if you are afraid of corrupt files after a resume, you could add `--checksum` to force it to do checksumming on the whole file every time. Indeed it will cost you some disk-IO and CPU cycles, but only a slight network overhead.

Comment: My understanding from `man rsync` is checksums control rsync's determination of what to transfer, not a post-transfer validation, if that's what you're suggesting?  I can't see how file size and modtime will be the same (thus requiring checksum) if `--inplace` is used and a connection is dropped.  To ensure data-correctness, the OP would need to run a second rsync with `-c`.